# MYSQL Installation does not work

Tags: mysql

I got this error:

```
root@bananapi:~# sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
mysql-server-5.5
Suggested packages:
mailx tinyca
Recommended packages:
libhtml-template-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
mysql-server-5.5
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1616 kB of archives.
After this operation, 29.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 54015 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.54-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
groupadd: existing lock file /etc/group.lock without a PID
groupadd: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.
addgroup: `/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 114 mysql' returned error code 10. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-  5.5_5.5.54-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.54-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried many different solutions, but for me nothing worked. So i purged and reinstalled it, but it does not work.
Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Just `sudo rm -f /etc/group.lock`